# Android Speech recognition by pocketsphinx with full english dump

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I need to convert speech to text using pocketsphinx with full english dump.So i can see the any result.

I have follow many tutorial and tried to find the solution but didn't success till now.

I have follow main demo of pocketsphinx.It show me predefined grammer so i can speak between 3 word. then i got result.

Is there any way to use english dump so i can search anything and using pocketsphinx get result.

I have search alot but not got any demo like this. Some i got but that is not working in android or some have partial information. 
If somebody have earlier tried it and get success then please help me to come out this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMUSphinx PocketSphinx - Recognize all (or large amount) of english words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-english-words)

Comment: It is currently not possible to recognize with large model on android, mobile phones are too slow. You might try on powerful tablet, but otherwise you need a significant of R&D to run this.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply.. I just need to confirm one more thing is this possible.. During call speech to text by using any API.or lib or any other stuff