# How to get the out put text from pocket sphinx android

Tags: android, pocketsphinx-android

I'm working on android project and i needed an offline Speech to Text API, and i choose Pocket sphinx android. What i want sphinx to do is to return the converted text output not to check the input text(which should be passed to the *SpeechRecognizer* class 'startListening' method) with the voice. So how can i do that?

```
package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;
import static edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer;

public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements
        RecognitionListener {

    /* Named searches allow to quickly reconfigure the decoder */
    private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
    private static final String FORECAST_SEARCH = "forecast";
    private static final String DIGITS_SEARCH = "digits";
    private static final String PHONE_SEARCH = "phones";
    private static final String MENU_SEARCH = "menu";

    /* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
    private static final String KEYPHRASE = "oh mighty computer";

    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        // Prepare the data for UI
        captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
        captions.put(MENU_SEARCH, R.string.menu_caption);
        captions.put(DIGITS_SEARCH, R.string.digits_caption);
        captions.put(PHONE_SEARCH, R.string.phone_caption);
        captions.put(FORECAST_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

        // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
        // so we execute it in async task

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
            @Override
            protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
                    File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                    setupRecognizer(assetDir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return e;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                            .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
                } else {
                    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        recognizer.cancel();
        recognizer.shutdown();
    }

    /**
     * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
     * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
     * for final result in onResult.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        if (hypothesis == null)
            return;

        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
            switchSearch(MENU_SEARCH);
        else if (text.equals(DIGITS_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
        else if (text.equals(PHONE_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(PHONE_SEARCH);
        else if (text.equals(FORECAST_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH);
        else
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
    }

    /**
     * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
     */
    @Override
    public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
        if (hypothesis != null) {
            String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
            makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    }

    /**
     * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
     */
    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }

    private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
        recognizer.stop();

        // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
        if (searchName.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
            recognizer.startListening(searchName);
        else
            recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);

        String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
    }

    private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
        // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
        // of different kind and switch between them

        recognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

                // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)
                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)

                // Threshold to tune for keyphrase to balance between false alarms and misses
                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45f)

                // Use context-independent phonetic search, context-dependent is too slow for mobile
                .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)

                .getRecognizer();
        recognizer.addListener(this);

        /** In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
         * They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
         */

        // Create keyword-activation search.
        recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

        // Create grammar-based search for selection between demos
        File menuGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "menu.gram");
        recognizer.addGrammarSearch(MENU_SEARCH, menuGrammar);

        // Create grammar-based search for digit recognition
        File digitsGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "digits.gram");
        recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);

        // Create language model search
        File languageModel = new File(assetsDir, "weather.dmp");
        recognizer.addNgramSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH, languageModel);

        // Phonetic search
        File phoneticModel = new File(assetsDir, "en-phone.dmp");
        recognizer.addAllphoneSearch(PHONE_SEARCH, phoneticModel);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception error) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeout() {
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code so we can undertand your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMUSphinx PocketSphinx - Recognize all (or large amount) of english words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-english-words)