# Continuous voice recognition using pocketsphinx

Tags: android, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I'm an intern at company that work on AI and related projects. I've been assigned on a teaching tablet android project in which the player can communicate with the game using speech. So I've been exploring open-source API's that support Continuous speech recognition using Java and i found cmu sphinx for android https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo.git but the android demo application works based on keyword search, but what i want from the engine is that to give me continuous output text. How can i fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMUSphinx PocketSphinx - Recognize all (or large amount) of english words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-english-words)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your grammar file and dictionary according to the sentence.

```
    public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {

    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
   }
```

Print the text and perform modification according to your choice.