# How to use models for new language in pocketsphinx

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I have compiled a language model ,dictionary and acoustic model etc all necessary to convert speech to text in my native language. so, when I use this command on the linux terminal

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm <your_new_model_folder> -lm <your_lm> -dict <your_dict> -inmic yes
```

I am able to convert my speech to text in the terminal. Now, I want to implement this on android.This [android tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) requires threshold etc but I am not using any of those.  I just want to use the same implementation that I was able to achieve in linux.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMUSphinx PocketSphinx - Recognize all (or large amount) of english words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-english-words)