# Continuous Language Recognition on Pocket SPhinx

Tags: pocketsphinx

I am trying to implement the voice recognition using pocketSphinx. Currently, i am able to recognize multiple phrases from the grammar file.  using

```
recognizer.addKeywordSearch(KWS_SEARCH,menuGrammar);
```

The issue, is only the exact phrases from the grammar file get recognized. I want to be able to recognize ( and print) more English like statements. If I am able to retrieve the statements spoken by the user, i will then search for certain keywords ( and then do the required action)
Can you please guide me on how to recognise multiple statements spoken by the user ( without having to force the user to say the specific phrases as it is)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMUSphinx PocketSphinx - Recognize all (or large amount) of words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-words)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, i followed the code in the above link.But the recognizer continuously prints the words. Is this the issue again with the threshold. I use the following code

Comment: recognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))               
                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)
                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45f) // changing the treshold
                .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)
                .getRecognizer();
        recognizer.addListener(this);
    File nGramSearch = new File(assetsDir, "en-us.lm.bin");
        recognizer.addNgramSearch(KWS_SEARCH,nGramSearch);