# pocketSphinx-android for STT(Speech to Text) instead of searching for keywords?

Tags: android, android-studio, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx-android

I'm trying to build a speech to text app using pocketSphinx-Android demo. But the code in the demo is for searching specific words like digits, phones, etc.

```
    `// Create keyword-activation search.
      recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
     // Create grammar-based search for selection between demos
      File menuGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "menu.gram");
      recognizer.addGrammarSearch(MENU_SEARCH, menuGrammar);

    // Create grammar-based search for digit recognition
      File digitsGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "digits.gram");
      recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);

    // Create language model search
      File languageModel = new File(assetsDir, "weather.dmp");
      recognizer.addNgramSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH, languageModel);

    // Phonetic search
      File phoneticModel = new File(assetsDir, "en-phone.dmp");
      recognizer.addAllphoneSearch(PHONE_SEARCH, phoneticModel);`
```

I'm not looking for searches for keywords like NGRAM_SEARCH. With just one keyword, I need the app to listen to what the user is saying and convert it directly to text.In [CMUSphinx PocketSphinx - Recognize all (or large amount) of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-words) , it uses another word other than the keyword to activate receiving input from the user. I need **a simple STT Engine that activates with just one keyword just like google assistant**. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMUSphinx PocketSphinx - Recognize all (or large amount) of words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-words)