# pocketsphinx android continuous speech

Tags: android, pocketsphinx

is it possible to do continuous speech recognition using pocketsphinx android?. the concept of the project is to convert the speech(lecture of a professor) to text. the android demo was used for keyword only. If not possible can you suggest some api that can support continuous speech. Thanks in an advice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMUSphinx PocketSphinx - Recognize all (or large amount) of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-words)

Comment: thanks sir @NikolayShmyrev for your suggestion. I want to ask more if it is possible to use continuous speech in pocketsphinx android like what I saw in shpinx4 for windows? your answer is very appreciated :)

Comment: No it is not possible