# Pocketsphinx android demo with arabic model doesn't work as the pc model

Tags: pocketsphinx-android

I'm working on pocket-sphinx android demo .. I have tried my model on the PC .. but on the mobile it is not as good as the PC .. I thought of modifing the code to insert an audio file instead of recording from the mic of the mobile . Can anyone tellme what can I change in the code to do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to dump audio files and listen for them and try to recognize them. If there are breaks it means your recognizer is not fast enough, you need to optimize the model size.

Comment: I still cant modify the code to take audio file instead of the mic and upon using the mic the app doesn't respond and give random words.

Comment: You do not need to modify the code, you dump the files and recognize them on PC, you can also simply listen to them.

Comment: I did that but the raw files are either empty or noise although it detects, could it be that i'm using large lm and not gram the model works fine on PC???

Comment: Share them. Yes, big model will not work as described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-words/25951895#25951895

Comment: those are the raw files https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a_I_tWmt-IXFvgBzgK8sJ5tN7_zxEILk

Comment: The audio is ok, you can listen in audacity.Now how do you configure the model and also show the logcat output.

Comment: Also can i change the initial number of densities when i change it i get an error that the mean file is defined as as initial 1 and stops before training