# Openears detecting words not in the dictionary and/or language file

Tags: ios, dictionary, vocabulary, openears

I am working on a navigation app that utilizes voice recognition to point the user towards their destination. However, this may require phrases or words outside what might be obvious. "Navigate to" would be simple, since I can add it to the dictionary, but "starbucks" won't be so easy. I could simply add starbucks, but that only solves one venue out of the hundreds of thousands that have non-standard names. I am looking for a way to do this in a more widespread way.

Is there any way to setup or configure Openears to detect and understand all words said?

Comment: In case someone finds this--It seems near impossible. My only reply this got was "try dragon" which got deleted for not being helpful enough.

Comment: I answered this in other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638672/recognize-large-vocabulary-free-form-speech-with-openears/34642078#34642078

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large vocabulary speech recognition in iPhone without internet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771319/large-vocabulary-speech-recognition-in-iphone-without-internet)