# Open ears Speech to text predefined text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, openears

I am using open ears library but in various code samples it states that there should be a predefined set of words.
But i dont want this, it should just convert to text what I speak.

For example :

```
NSArray *words = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"WORD", @"STATEMENT", @"OTHER WORD", @"A PHRASE", nil];
NSString *name = @"NameIWantForMyLanguageModelFiles";
NSError *err   = [lmGenerator generateLanguageModelFromArray:words withFilesNamed:name forAcousticModelAtPath:[OEAcousticModel pathToModel:@"AcousticModelEnglish"]];
```

I dont want to use words array, instaead i want to convert my speech to text

Any help on this ?

Comment: it looks like this is not possible, as stated in the [FAQs](http://www.politepix.com/openears/support/#Q_Can_I_use_OpenEars_without_defining_a_vocabulary_Can_I_use_OpenEars_to_recognize_any_word_the_user_might_say). You could use the new speech recognition API in iOS 10, which is presented [in this talk from WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large vocabulary speech recognition in iPhone without internet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771319/large-vocabulary-speech-recognition-in-iphone-without-internet)